# Can i integrate S translator in my app

Tags: android

In my app i want to use galaxy s4 S-translator.So is it possible to use it? And normally can i call another app from my app.I am very new to android.So I don't know it is possible or not.So if possible plz tell me.I think by using intent with giving proper action we can do it.

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
if (i == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

thanx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using intents.

For example:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.theotherapp", "com.example.theotherapp.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

This is called an explicit intent, because you're explicitly stating which component should respond to it. You can also use implicit intents, in which you specify what kind of component you expect and the OS and/or the user selects the most appropriate one.

If you can choose, implicit intents are preferred.

This might Help You.

Comment: Thanx for ur response.So In this way can i use Samsung galaxy s tranlator.The package name is com.sec.android.app.translator.

Comment: Yes,you can try and please accept the answer if it works. Thank you